# How to sort command line arguments alphabetically in C++ by pointers

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, pointers

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    // Display each command-line argument.
    for( i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
        cout << "  argv[" << i << "]   " << argv[i] << "\n";
}
```

How can I sort the ouput alphabetically by pointers?

Comment: The C++ standard library have many nice [algorithm functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), including [functions for sorting](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm#Sorting_operations). The question is *why* you want to do it? Just for display purposes? Is it a school (or similar) assignment?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I know,but I need to do it handy

Comment: Then read up on [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool mycmp(const string& a, const string &b) {
   return (a<=b);
}


int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    sort(argv+1, argv + argc, mycmp);
    for( i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
        cout << "  argv[" << i << "]   " << argv[i] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I know the sort function, but I need to do it handy with pointers

Comment: @ebrahimhadi: What exactly does "handy" mean to you?

Comment: for example using for loop, comparing character by character, pointers pointing to the cmd args.....

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - it means that it can be handed in as a homework answer.

Comment: The comparison function you pass is really supposed to correspond to `<`, not `<=` as you've done here.

Comment: There is no need at all to use a comparison function - the built-in one is perfectly fine

Comment: @anatolyg: If it was an array of `std::string`, it would be. But as an array of pointers, it is not.